# Newline in WindowMessage

Tags: java

i'm new in java, i try to add new lines in a message string:

```
String message = "Test User1,\n Test User2,\n Test User1";
WindowMessage win2 = new WindowMessage("The following Names are duplicate : "+messages);
win2.setModal(true);
app.addWindow(win2);
```

i tried to add \r\n, \n, %r%n, %n, but none of them working

in my WindowMessage(**extends WindowPane**) class, the Message is set as a Label:

```
lblMessage.setText(Message);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: when i double backslashes, it displays "\n" in the message, when i triple backslashes, it displays "\"

Comment: For starters, it appears that you're using 3 different variable names for the message. `message`, `messages`, and `Message`. Perhaps some code you haven't shared would clarify any differences among these 3 variables. As for new line characters, you could try `String message = String.format("Test User1,\n Test User2,\n Test User1");`

Comment: what's the type of `lblMessage`? does it even support multi-line text display?

Comment: import nextapp.echo.app.Label;
It seems to not support multi line text

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which API you're using, but try using a `JLabel` with html:

```
JLabel l = new JLabel("<html>line1<br>line2</html>");
```

If you are using a library that does not support multilines within the same label (check the docs!), then you should stack two labels on top of each other:

```
Label line1 = ...
Label line2 = ...
```

If you do not have control over how many labels you can add, then what you are trying to do is not possible with your library.

Comment: i use EchoStudio 3, and it not supporting html codes :(

Comment: i don't have control over how many Labels i need :(
To all, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: This is working on localhost, but not on my server, really strange

Comment: Is there any difference in the security settings or jdk variant/version?

Comment: im' gonna look at that